# Is there a smaller version of Stanford CoreNLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to reduce the size of a plugin (written in java) I am working on and we use CoreNLP to parse some text. We don't use too many features of CoreNLP, but it is by far the largest component of the plugin and makes downloading it more burdensome than desired for the end user. I am aware of the Simple CoreNLP API as well as the Client/Server functionality that is featured with CoreNLP, but it still seems to require downloading the entire package along with the models. Is there another version that is smaller, or has someone else made something smaller with a little less functionality? The only annotators we use are the tokenizer, ssplit, parse, sentiment analysis, the part of speech tagger, and the lemmatizer.

Answer (score 0):

I will just add in that if you make a jar with just the models for the annotators you are using you can cut the size down a lot.  The models are what take up most of the space, and you only need the ones you are using.

Comment: With the annotators I'm using, I'm guessing I only need the parser, pos-tagger, and sentiment models. Is that correct? Or are there others like lexparser or upos that I would need?

Comment: When you run the pipeline it will log what it is loading...you should only need those things.  But you should be fine with a parser model,a part of speech model, and the sentiment models.